# How to install gnome shell extensions without installing ppa repo in 13.10?

Tags: gnome

People had warned me that ppa repositories are not reliable and which can break my system.

Also themes without ppa would be nice to know how to install with Unity and Gnome Shell.

Is there a way to install gnome shell and it's extension without ppa repositories?

Comment: Gnome shell should be available in the default repositories, but it will be an older version than you would probably find in any PPA. Also for what I can tell the extensions can be installed directly from https://extensions.gnome.org (you may need to use Firefox)

Comment: @Salem I recommend posting that (or something like it) as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it on 14.04 recently.  You could try it in 13.10, it might work the same.

```
$ sudo apt-get install gdm gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Note, if you want to keep your ability to run unity, you might want to skip installing gdm.  I've had better experience going full gnome, all the time and just using gdm, but gdm is not compatible with unity.